# How to search by JSON in Postgresql (Java)

Tags: java, postgresql, search, text

I wanna search record in Postgresql. I have a Table and have a column which is created as a Text datatype (called A column). In A column I save data as JSON data type. 
For example:

```
ID             A column
1              {"A1":["1"]}
2              {"A2":["2"], "B":["3"]}
```

I am using Java to search data. My condition search is "A1":["1", "2"].
How to I can search?
Please help me to solve problem!

Comment: How are you using java to search data? Why not use SQL? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ("A column"->'A1') = '["1", "2"]'::json`

Comment: 'A column' datatype is text. When I run above SQL, I got a Error message: operator does not exist: text -> unknown.

Comment: you can cast it to JSON then: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ("A column"::json->'A1') = '["1", "2"]'::json`

Comment: Oh no. also error -> ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = json

Comment: oh yes, I forgot. This way then `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ("A column"::json->>'A1') = '["1", "2"]'`

Comment: Here is my query:` select * from table where ("A column"::json ->> 'Month') = '["1", "2"]'`. I get an error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tab (ID int, "A column" text);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES 
  (1, '{"A1":["1"]}'),
  (2, '{"A2":["2"], "B":["3"]}'),
  (3, '{"A2":["1","2"], "B":["3"]}');

SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ("A column"::json->>'A2') = '["1","2"]';
```

It will only work if all of the values in `"A column"` are properly formatted json. Otherwise you'd have to use a function to trap the conversion exceptions and return null when it is an invalid json value.

---

#### Update

If you want all the fields with a value within a set, then

```
SELECT * FROM tab 
WHERE ARRAY(select json_array_elements_text("A column"::json->'A2')::text)
        && ARRAY['1','2'];
```

Comment: oh. Thank you so much. But I want to that when run query `SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ("A column"::json->>'A2') = '["1","2"]';`, result will be ID 1, 2 and 3. Now only record which has ID = 3 is returned.